# POST http://localhost:5173/submit-record 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, backend

Currently what I am trying to do is to obtain username data and timeTaken from a form. I want to then take that data and send it to my server and create the User object and then store it in MongoDB Atlas.

But currently I am getting this error 404 issue and I do not know how to fix it, can anyone help>

For some context, the frontend is using React and the backend is using Express and MongoDB. There may be some stuff not being used its because I made a fresh express project just a bit ago to try and see if my issue would go away.

modal.jsx: the modal here is the form I was referring to.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import "../App.css"


function Modal({ time, onClose }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(''); // State to store the username

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/submit-record', {
        username,
        time,
      });
  
      if (response.status === 201) {
        // Handle success (e.g., close the modal)
        onClose();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting record:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div className="modal-content">
      <input className='username-input'
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <p className="timeTaken">Time Taken: {time} seconds</p>
        <button className="close-Button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Modal;
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const User = require('./models/user.js'); // Import the Mongoose model

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('blank for now so i can post here', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

var app = express();

const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS for all routes

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

console.log("TEST");
// Define the route for submitting records directly on the app object
app.post('/submit-record', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, timeTaken } = req.body;
  console.log('Received POST request to /submit-record', req.body);

  try {
    // Create a new user instance and save it to the database
    const user = new User({ username, timeTaken });
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Record saved successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving record:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

app.listen(5173, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 5173');
});


module.exports = app;
```

I've asked ChatGPT for some solutions and I have restarted the server, used POSTMAN, check for typos, used a test server, remake my server code many times and the issue still persists.

Comment: "*used POSTMAN*" - what happened then? Have you set up correct proxy to direct at `"http://localhost:5173"`?

Comment: @Aleksandar Postman gave me the same error 404, and yes, I have set up a proxy like as you stated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, can you for a test define a route: `app.get('/test', (req, res) => {res.send('Works')}` and open the browser at `http://localhost:5173/test` and tell me do you see the message "Works"?

Comment: If you are using `Vite version 4`, for React, which runs at PORT `5173` by default, then I'm not sure why would you conflict that frontend PORT by running your backend at the same PORT on purpose? Again, I'm not saying it's wrong if you know what you're doing; but it's much more naturally to run the server at PORT `3000`.